# Login for Server-side Apps (Facebook PHP SDK)

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, server-side

I am currently following a technical guide.(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/)

I am stuck in between Step 6 and 7.
Can anybody help me?

As file_get_contents() does not work, I am wondering if I could change this part

```
 $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
 $params = null;
 parse_str($response, $params);
```

to

```
 $response = curl($token_url);
 $params = null;
 parse_str($response, $params);
```

whereas my cUrl function is:

```
  function curl($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
```

Comment: 1. This could be tried in less time than it took to post the question. 2. Why doesn't `file_get_contents()` work? It may well be relevant.

Comment: Hi ceejayoz, I kept getting 400 Bad Request from my file_get_contents(), therefore I tried using cUrl instead.

Comment: You should figure out why you're getting a 400 Bad Request, then, because you're almost certainly going to get it with cURL too. I'd suggest printing out `$token_url` and visiting it in your browser to see what error it's spitting out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ceejayoz, I have found out my error.

When I print out my $token_url, I found out that my variables are wrongly formatted thus causing the error. I was too careless.